# Parsing XML, calling doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName() and get a bad output of "h1"?

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

Here is my code: (source: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/)

Here is my XML file: removed

On run, the NoResults appears and I get the string "h1" which isn't a xml tag in my file.
I am not sure if my xml file is being converted incorrectly or I can't successfully find the "members" tag.

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parse = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parse.getXmlFromUrl(url); // getting XML
    Document doc = parse.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_MEMBER);

    // looping through all item nodes <member>
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {                           
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    

        Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
        map.put(KEY_FNAME, parse.getValue(e, KEY_FNAME));
        map.put(KEY_MNAME, parse.getValue(e, KEY_MNAME));
        map.put(KEY_LNAME, parse.getValue(e, KEY_LNAME));
        map.put(KEY_STATE, parse.getValue(e, KEY_STATE));
        map.put(KEY_PARTY, parse.getValue(e, KEY_PARTY));
        mylist.add(map);            
    }

    if((nodes.getLength() <= 0)){
            Toast.makeText(AndroidXMLParsingActivity.this, "NoResults " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "h1" is an html tag, i would guess that the url your are hitting is returning html, not xml.  an easy way to determine this, of course, would be to print out the xml string before you parse it.

fyi, not sure about the limitations of coding on android, but it's generally a bad idea to convert an xml document to string before you parse it (for a variety of reasons ranging from "breaking" the xml to needlessly increasing the memory usage).

Comment: Interesting, I am pretty sure its an xml file because it opens up as an xml file in internet explorer when I visit the very same URL.

Comment: Scratch that, I just tried it from my dropbox link and I am getting force closes (I think thats else where). THANK YOU!